# disabled inputs make holes in DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello i have a div and inside of the div there is a table full of inputs, some of them are disabled and some of them not... 
the div is there to trigger a js function when the mouse is over it, but when i go over an input which is disabled it behaves like i am not in the div anymore.
The table is actualy important here...(not in this small example but in the full code)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
            <button onclick="visible()">fasd</button>
  <div id="id" onmouseover="visible()" onmouseout="invisible()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type = "submit" name="inputs" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input type = "submit" name="inputs"></td>
        <td><input type = "submit" name="inputs" disabled="disabled"></td>
        <td><input type = "submit" name="inputs"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function visible()
{
    document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "visible";
}
function invisible()
{
    document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

is there any way how make this work? Thanks a lot for every reply

Comment: Where's your JS? This is just some markup that doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: I am sorry... JS added

Comment: You're currently trying to hide and show an element with the literally id `id`? What element is that?

Comment: yes.. i am sorry.., again.. it's the div...

Comment: now it should be complete.. i am sorry for the uncomplete codes that i've poseted.. i shoud test them before posting... :(

Answer (score 0):

This

```
document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Makes the element transparent, but still occupies the space. While this

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";
```

Hides the element and the element will not occupy spaces.

And the property `id` is suppose to contain unique value across the entire page, so there can be only **one** `id="id"` in your document.

Comment: ok.. thans... 
also i am sorry.. the example was bad.. the id shout be given to the div not to the inputs...
it works.., it hides the tables when i am outside the div.. the probles is that it hides the table also when i am over an disabled input...

Comment: @Atom - Example? So this isn't your actual code? Please don't post rewrites of your real code. We need to see the real deal. Use copy/paste. Debugging rewrites or pseudo code is a waste of time since you (as proven) can introduce other issues.

Comment: Yes.. i am sorry... the whole code is too long..., so i tried to make it as short as possible...

Comment: @Atom Go through your code and post all the relevant parts. We don't need to see things that's unrelated to the feature you're struggling with.

Comment: yes.. you right.., i am sorry.. now it should be it... i've tested this pice of non working code and it has exact same behaviour....
when i hover over the non disabled inputs it's ok, but when i hover over the disabled ones, it makes the table inivisble... :(